# $|x_{n+1} - x_n | \le C|x_n - x_{n-1}|$ (show that $x_n$ is Cauchy)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

> Let$\{x_n\}$ be a sequence such that there exists a $0<C<1$ such that 
>   $$|x_{n+1} - x_n | \le C|x_n - x_{n-1}|.$$
>   Prove that $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy. Hint: You can freely use the formula (for $C \not=1$) 
>   $$1+C+C^2+...+ C^n = \frac{1-C^{n+1}}{1-C}.$$

Let $x_n - x_{n-1} = y_n$. Then, $\frac{|y_{n+1}|}{|y_n|}\le C < 1$. This implies that $y_n$ converges to $0$ by ratio test. I also have the theorem that $y_n$ converges iff $y_n$ is Cauchy. But, I think that this does not mean $x_n$ is Cauchy. Could you give me some help? How can I use the hint given?

Comment: Hint: $|x_{n+k} - x_n| = |x_{n+k} - x_{n+k-1} + ... - x_n| \le |x_{n+k}-x_{n+k-1}| + ... + |x_{n+1} - x_n| \le (C^k + ... + 1)|x_{n+1}-x_n| \le (C^k + ... +1)C^n |x_1 - x_0|$

Comment: Since you accepted an answer that comment feels a bit rhetorical...

Comment: @ArnaudD. Oh. I couldn't find my question, so I thought that it was deleted. Thanks anyway.